# Free way to create flash content, OpenLaszlo?

Tags: flash, free

I am an experienced web developer on a shoestring budget. What **free** or *very inexpensive* ways exist to create a website using Adobe Flash?

Even low-level manipulations would be appreciated, like an actionscript compiler, so I could design something basic like an interactive map.

**Update**: What is OpenLaszlo? Can it compile everything into a .swf or do I still require adobe's tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both OpenLaszlo and the official [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK) are open-source, so basically any good text editor (I'd suggest [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) on Windows or VM) or IDE can be used to create full-fledged ActionScript projects. If you're mainly interested in point-and-click, design-based environments, though, you may find yourself limited to the relatively expensive Adobe Flash IDE. There have been a few attempts to create alternative IDEs, but (in my opinion) none that come close to offering a full authoring environment. (Check osflash.org for other possibilities, though.)

If none of these options fit your needs, and you just want to make something quick and simple without investing a lot of time and effort, you may find it best to simply hire a freelance developer/designer to create the piece you need.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) (or see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWFTools)). It's a free command-line  based SWF file creator/manipulator suite.  Windows binaries and *nix source available.